# Get window top from <object> tag

Tags: javascript, html, browser, window

Is it possible to fetch the window data of the "parent" window, from within a page loaded in a  tag ?
I'm embedding a remote html file from https://test-static-app.herokuapp.com/ which simply outputs window.top and window.parent.top in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('window.top', window.top.location);
        console.log('window.parent.top', window.parent.top.location);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is for both values:

```
{}
```

Is it possible to get this data? How ?

Comment: You can't access frames from other origins, due to [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/). If your parent and page are from different domains, this won't work.

Comment: @ssube thanks! What if i enable CORS on my page? Would it then work?

Comment: If CORS is enabled and figured for both domains, then this should be possible.